# Why Checkbox animation doesn't show in Flutter?

Tags: animation, checkbox, flutter

I used **Checkbox** to update some data. The sharing data method is `Consumer<T>`.
The problem is that Checkbox can work ok on changing state, but the checking animation is missing.
I have located the problem, if I used `notifyListeners()`to notify the Data changed, then the animation of Checkbox is missing.

The Widget code just like below:

```
bool _value = false;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Checkbox(
          activeColor: Colors.green,
          value: _value,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _value = value;
              widget.updateEnergy(); //The problem is Here!!!!!
            });
          },
        ),

        Text("foodName",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue,
              fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
        ),

        Spacer(),

      ],
    );
  }
```

If I used the `widget.updateEnergy();` to update the data in `onChanged()`, the animation is missing.
The updateEnergy() as below:

```
void updateCurrentEnergy(){
    _currentEnergyCount.setValue(_getCurrentEnergyCount(), _dailyTargetEnergy.unit);

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

The key is "notifyListeners()", if removed the invoke, the animation is return.
And my data class is "with ChangeNotifier", so `notifyListeners()` is from **ChangeNotifier**.
And I used the `ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: dailyRecord)`, to share the data in the father node. And user the `Consumer<DailyRecord>(...`using data.

I hope your help, how can get the animation of checkbox.
Thank you!

Comment: is your class extending a `ChangeNotifier`? if not, post your`notifyListeners` method

Comment: Yes, I "with ChangeNotifier". @pskink

Comment: I used `claas TestState extends State<Test> with ChangeNotifier { ...` and it works just fine

Comment: @pskink, thank you first. My data Class is just like ```class DailyRecord with ChangeNotifier{...```, is it the reason? I didn't use the State. Because it just the Data Model.

Comment: I don't know, I just declared my class as above added addListener() inside initState() and called notifyListeners() inside onChanged callback

Comment: I used **ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: dailyRecord),** to share the data. So I didn't use the "addListener()".Maybe it is the problem. Thank you all the same.

Comment: If the `initState` of the widget you shared being run again?

Comment: Because I used the ChangeNotifierProvider, so I have no need initState about "addListener" or removeListener.